# What's the view on closing questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Watching Stack Overflow over the past few days I see questions often being closed rather overzealously.  There are definitely some questions that deserve to be closed (e.g. "Do my homework", etc) but it's a shame that other questions get closed despite being marked as community wiki; e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304287/what-are-the-common-disorders-diseases-the-programmers-suffer-from-closed

My view is that this type of slightly off-topic-but-still-interesting question enriches the SO community (you only have to view the number of people who responded to this), and I wondered what other people thought?

Also, have people noticed a change in attitudes towards closing questions?  For example, I see that no one has closed this SO "classic": [What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon).

Comment: Oh... not again...

Comment: @Juan: Sorry ... I don't follow meta that closely.  Don't tell me - This is a dupe.

Comment: If only you knew how many times the cartoon question has been referenced...

Comment: Another appeal to common practice. Why is logic so hard to find amongst programmers?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/84556/list Programmer Cartoon has been closed and reopened 3 times before being locked open by the Community.

Comment: If only you knew how many times the cartoon question has been closed... (it's more than 3 - close / open events didn't used to show up in the revision history)

Comment: I wish there were a close reason of "mentions that stupid cartoon question."

Comment: @Pesto: Or at least "Based around logical fallacy."

Comment: @Adamski: I suggest you do a search on `[closed-questions]`.

Answer (score 7):

Community Wiki isn't carte blanche to post *anything* you want. It doesn't allow you to sidestep the normal rules/guidelines of SO posts. This is still a Q/A site and extended discussion is frowned upon be it CW or not. Likewise, if the primary topic/focus of the question does not relate to actual *programming*, it is usually going to get closed whether or not it is CW.

With respect to old questions (like ["programmer cartoons"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon)) they are effectively grandfathered-in to the site. They were created in the early days when posting guidelines were still being hammered out, and they have had so much activity that most people just let them be. They sit in the background as a little bit of noise, museum pieces of the early days of SO.

Comment: Lies, they were put there by Jon Skeet to test our faith.

Comment: If they're tests, did we pass or fail?

Comment: I passed, you failed.

Comment: I passed, but I copied off of jjnguy.

Comment: I failed, but I copied off of jinguy too.

Comment: @jjnguy: "Pics or it didn't happen."

Answer (score 2):

I know **exactly** what you mean *Adamski*! I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295616/why-are-there-no-simple-io-utils-in-the-jdk-for-reading-an-entire-file-into-a-str) yesterday because I'd made an assumption about the answer in a separate explanation and suddenly I wasn't so sure and wanted clarification.

It's programming related, it's a genuine question (albeit subjective) and it got closed! I would expect a *little* leeway given I've been on SO for almost a year. I've only voted to close a small handful of questions, eitehr because they are terribly-formed, homework or completely off-topic.

Some people here seem to be far too trigger-happy for my liking.

Comment: Er, why has this been downvoted?

Comment: Your question is unanswerable. We cannot tell you why someone did something. If you read the FAQ, you will see that questions asked on SO.com should be answerable.

Comment: `String wholeFile = new Scanner(pathToFile).useDeliminter("\\Z").next();`

Comment: Your question calls for speculation.  It probably would have survived had it been CW, though.

Comment: @Rich B - This site is *meta* not SO. No question is too trivial or newbie to ask and any question about SO is relevant. That's what it says in the 1st paragraph of the `faq`. Perhaps you are confused

Comment: @Pesto - true enough. I didn't make it CW because I felt that it was a genuine question. I wasn't asking "Why did they X" as a whine, I was asking "Why did they X" in case someone knew the answer!

Comment: @Rich B - the question was eminently answerable

Comment: @Rich B - good grief - you've downvoted my SO question as well! Thanks for that. **It was a genuine question!**: I really want to know the answer. It's programming related. SO is a programming Q&A site. I hope you can sleep at night (ed. you've gone too far)!

Comment: @oxbow: The question is not answerable. It is clearly not ok with the FAQ. Sorry. No argument you are going to make is going to make that question less subjective.

Comment: @Rich. SO how come you have answered these questions? They are subjective and unanswerable. Clearly against the FAQ and the spirit of *SO*. I implore you to remove your answers! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114342/what-are-code-smells-what-is-the-best-way-to-correct-them/114359#114359 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141110/what-is-the-single-software-company-that-you-most-want-to-work-for-why/141252#141252 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424952/are-single-threaded-applications-a-dead-technology/424974#424974 to name but three

Answer (score 1):

It's a shame that the question you first linked to got closed??  I disagree.

Questions asked on the sites should have clear answers solving a specific problem.

While the question you point out may have clear answers, they are not solving any particular programming problem.

<sub>At least, that's my opinion.</sub>

Comment: I thought that marking as Community Wiki meant that the post was more discussion-related, rather than question that required a clear answer?

Comment: So, posts that are more discussion related should be CW.  However, that doesn't mean that I think they are ok.

Comment: @Adamski: I think you are missing a large part of how this site works. I recommend reading the FAQ to start and then lurking here a while to understand the community opinion on these types of topics.

Comment: @Rich B - by "site" do you mean SO or *Meta*? Adamski has almost 3,000 points so has clearly been on SO a while

Comment: @oxbow: Rep is not an indicator of knowledge of the site or of anything else. He is demonstrating a clear (and startling) misunderstanding of how SO works.

Comment: @Rich B: Thanks, I took your advice and read the FAQ. In particular I noticed "Be nice." and "Bring your sense of humour." :-)

Comment: @Rich - your arrogance is quite astounding. The point of SO is of course to be a great place for Q&As. However, this only happens if people are encouraged to ask questions and post answers and forming relationships helps greatly in this. And of course, discussion help form relationships. As has been mentioned a gazillion times, if you don't want to see `offtopic` or `subjective` questions, filter them out!

Comment: @Adamski: Does the FAQ really say "humour"?  I better go fix that spelling mistake...

Comment: @Pesto: Humour is the English spelling.

Comment: @Adamski: Sure, but it also gives clear guidelines for appropriate questions which you seem to be ignoring.

Comment: @oxbow: SO.com is not a discussion forum. Simple. No matter how much you want it to be.

Comment: @Rich - The FAQ also states that any question relating to SO may be asked here and that "No question is too trivial or too "newbie"." so I'm confused as to how I've ignored these guidelines.  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Adamski: The question is not too "trivial or newbie" I don't know of anyone who is claiming that.

Comment: @Rich: Please elaborate on which guidelines you think I'm ignoring.  Feel free to quote from the FAQ if you like.

Comment: @Adamski: If you couldn't read the FAQ yourself, I am not sure how me reciting it will change anything. But here goes: Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!